# gsoap databinding, how to access a sequence within the .h file generated by gsoap

Tags: c++, xml, data-binding, sequence, gsoap

I have no idea how to access FilenameType_sequence

```
class ns1__FilenameType
{ 
 public:

   // SEQUENCE OF ELEMENTS <xs:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
    $int                                  __size_FilenameType_sequence   1;  
    class __ns1__FilenameType_sequence
    {   
       // std::string with length 1
       std::string filename                       1;
    }                                   *__FilenameType_sequence       ;
    //  END OF SEQUENCE
    // A handle to the soap struct that manages this instance (automatically set)
    struct soap                         *soap                          ;
};
```

I tried using its new function and then setting ns1_*FilenameType->*_FilenameType_sequence = to my new object but that didn't work.

```
ns1__FilenameType_sequence * fnSeq = soap_new__ns1__FilenameType_sequence(soap, -1);
fnSeq->filename = "Name";
s1__FilenameType->__FilenameType_sequence = fnSeq;
```

I also thought that maybe the .push_back function would work but initial testing didn't pan out.  So now im all out of ideas.  Any new ones would be greatly appreciated.  Let me know if you need more information

Thanks

Josh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you're having the same problem as me the code is as follows

```
ns1__FilenameType_sequence * fnSeq = soap_new__ns1__FilenameType_sequence(soap, 2);
fnSeq[0].filename = "Becky";
fnSeq[1].filename = "Jen";
fnSeq[1].filename = "Cindy";

ns1__FilenameType->__size_FilenameType_sequence = 3;
ns1__FilenameType->__FilenameType_sequence = fnSeq;
```

so kinda intuitive but not realy, hope this helps